# Change from ListView to GridView using BLoC

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have recently been studying BLoC, and I can't figure out how to make it so that when you click on the button, depending on whether the ListView or GridView, the list display changes, you can do this for example:
child: return display List ? listView() : gridView();
But in this case, how can I change this variable in the widget file via BLoC?
Who can tell you how to do it all correctly or maybe someone has an article with an example, it looks like he could not find anything, thank you all.

Comment: I have a list of files displayed, the application will have a button that changes the display of the list, or it goes in a list as in ListView or as GridView squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a `BlocBuilder` and then you will have to either have a switch on your state, or maybe your state has a variable that does this. Your button will fire an event to your bloc instance that will change the state accordingly. But it is way too much to just explain it in a answer in detail.

The easiest way to learn about and implement the BLoC pattern in Flutter is the [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) package.

[They](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted) have [many](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial), [many](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertimertutorial) tutorials on how to do this. Pick one and read up on it.